# Possible compiler bug, local struct accessing static variable in function from template parameter (phew)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Could somebody explain why the following code doesn't work on Visual Studio C++ 2008/2010 if the marked line is commented out? Is it a compiler bug or am I doing something wrong? The code should output a sequence of 10 U's, but with the line removed it outputs nothing. The variable chr becomes 0 inside the FilledArray constructor. Thanks!

```
// returns a c-string which contains the char repeated a certain number of times
template<char THE_CHAR>
const char *RepeatChar(unsigned int uiNumber)
{
      // must be static so can be accessed by struct
      static const unsigned int uiMaxSize = 1024;
      static const char chr = THE_CHAR;
      char temp = chr; // comment out this line and it doesn't work

      assert(uiMaxSize > 0);
      assert(uiNumber <= uiMaxSize);

      static const struct FilledArray
      {
            char data[uiMaxSize + 1];

            FilledArray()
            {
                  // fill all but last with the char (space for terminator)
                  fill(data, data + uiMaxSize, chr);
                  data[uiMaxSize] = '\0';
            }

      } sFilledArray;

      // clever bit
      return sFilledArray.data + uiMaxSize - uiNumber;
}

int main()
{
      cout << RepeatChar<'U'>(10) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug... though the question would be: *what additional value does `chr` brings ?* ie, why don't you write `fill(data, data + uiMaxSize, THE_CHAR)` directly ?

Comment: Almost always when it's a compiler bug it isn't.

Comment: `data[uiMaxSize + 1] = '\0';` should be `data[uiMaxSize] = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this though and the original problem still exists.

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 behaves in a similar manner, even with `THE_CHAR` as an argument to `fill()`. See http://ideone.com/0KexHG

Comment: vc++ works with THE_CHAR as an argument, and also if you used chr+1 because this forces it to compute chr+1.  In this place it replaces chr+1 with the explicit character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug.  I changed the code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

// returns a c-string which contains the char repeated a certain number of times
template<char THE_CHAR>
const char *RepeatChar(unsigned int uiNumber)
{
      // must be static so can be accessed by struct
      static const unsigned int uiMaxSize = 1024;
      static const char chr = THE_CHAR;
//      char temp = chr; // comment out this line and it doesn't work

      static const struct FilledArray
      {
            char data[uiMaxSize + 1];

            FilledArray()
            {
              cout << "[" << chr << "]" << endl;
                  fill(data, data + uiMaxSize, chr);
                  data[uiMaxSize] = '\0';
            }

      } sFilledArray;

      return sFilledArray.data + uiMaxSize - uiNumber;
}

int main()
{
      cout << RepeatChar<'U'>(10) << endl;
}
```

Then disassemble the problem area, namely:

```
cout << "[" << chr << "]" << endl;
fill(data, data + uiMaxSize, chr);
data[uiMaxSize] = '\0';
```

And:

```
            cout << "[" << chr << "]" << endl;
00FA3273  push        offset std::endl (0F9E730h)  
00FA3278  push        offset string "]" (0FFE3C0h)  
00FA327D  push        55h  
00FA327F  push        offset string "[" (0FFE3BCh)  
00FA3284  push        offset std::cout (1011F80h)  
00FA3289  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0F9EF91h)  
00FA328E  add         esp,8  
00FA3291  push        eax  
00FA3292  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0F9FA3Bh)  
00FA3297  add         esp,8  
00FA329A  push        eax  
00FA329B  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0F9EF91h)  
00FA32A0  add         esp,8  
00FA32A3  mov         ecx,eax  
00FA32A5  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0F9EFD2h)  
                  fill(data, data + uiMaxSize, chr);
00FA32AA  push        offset `RepeatChar<85>'::`2'::chr (0FFE3BAh)  
00FA32AF  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
00FA32B2  add         eax,400h  
00FA32B7  push        eax  
00FA32B8  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
00FA32BB  push        ecx  
00FA32BC  call        std::fill<char *,char> (0F9E839h)  
00FA32C1  add         esp,0Ch  
                  data[uiMaxSize] = '\0';
00FA32C4  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
00FA32C7  mov         byte ptr [eax+400h],0
```

Notice that when used by cout <<, it explicitly replaces the character (55h) in place of *chr*:

```
00FA327D  push        55h
```

However, when used as a parameter in fill, it uses *offset `RepeatChar<85>'::`2'::chr (0FFE3BAh)* as in:

```
00FA32AA  push        offset `RepeatChar<85>'::`2'::chr (0FFE3BAh)
```

But memory location 0FFE3BAh contains a 0.  But if chr is used elsewhere, then it fills 55h at that location.

It looks like the code that generates static section thinks it has completely optimized out *chr*, but in reality it hasn't.

Unfortunately, we don't have the source code to VC++, so this will remain a mystery until Microsoft fixes it.

EDIT:

The same code does not compile in g++ 4.4.5.  Well, it actually compiles fine, but generates code that depends on an external that it seems to have left out, which causes the linker to barf.  I got the following error code when compiling with g++:

```
/tmp/cccGJmv9.o: In function `char const* RepeatChar<(char)85>(unsigned int)::FilledArray::FilledArray()':
b1.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `chr'
b1.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `uiMaxSize'
b1.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `chr'
b1.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `uiMaxSize'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is consistent with the diagnosis that it seems to have thought it optimized out the static const variables, but in reality, it hasn't.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the assembly very well but it's good to know it wasn't a bug in my code. I will write it a different way.